# More consistent wording for the synonyms creation page

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, terminology

[image]

The tag pages - such as https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all refer to "master" and "synonym."

The "create a tag synonym" page refers to them as "source" and "target."

[image]

Could we have them with consistent names?

Comment: It should be pointed out that the terminology in the Create Tag Synonyms tool is consistent with the Merge Tags tool (`/admin/merge-tags`, [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIZyf.png)), which I view as its closest relative. (Both of these tools have the option of performing the other at the same time.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let's have one set of terminology for tag synonyms, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295283/lets-have-one-set-of-terminology-for-tag-synonyms-please) - this question is older but doesn't have an answer.

Comment: I'm good with that. Also slightly distracted by a notice I don't recall seeing before. Also, Cat has a better chance of getting it fixed XD