# Give the fields in the moderator "Create tag synonym" form more descriptive titles

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms

Moderators have access to a handy-dandy tool for creating tag synonyms, which looks like this (screenshot from [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)):

[image: Create tag synonyms moderator-only tool]

Once you figure it out, it works nicely. But it's *not at all* obvious what goes into "source tag" and "target tag", respectively. (It might be obvious to a developer with intimate knowledge of the database schema.)

I humbly propose that the fields be renamed to be called **existing tag** and **new tag synonym**, respectively and as appropriate.

Doing so should make it immediately obvious which input goes where, reducing much confusion on part of diamond moderators.

Comment: Definitely related - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128956/layout-improvement-for-create-tag-synonym - not an exact duplicate though.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, I did find that one, but hopefully changing two labels in the UI is easier than reworking the UI (especially given that that one has been lingering for over five years...).

Comment: if you also merge, both tags are existing and the dialog might be confusing

Comment: @MadScientist in that case how about "Master" for the existing one? That covers both use cases.

Comment: @MadScientist One could even imagine a little bit of Javascript that changes the titles if you check the "merge" checkbox. Maybe then referring to the one that's left as "main tag after tag merge"? IMO almost anything would be clearer than what we've got right now...

Comment: It's obvious to *me* which is source and which is target (and I'm not any kind of developer or computery person). You map the source onto the target - simple as that. The page for creating a new tag *synonym* (not the mod merge tool, the one that's available to everyone), on the other hand, has always been unclear as heck to me.

Comment: @Randal'Thor the UI and labels are the same on both pages aren't they?

Comment: @Cai Nooo. The non-mod one looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQLlV.png). Which confuses the hell out of me: am I proposing a new tag to be mapped to [tagname]? am I proposing that the existing [tagname] be mapped to something else? "Source" and "target" is much clearer, IMO.

Comment: @Randal'Thor oh yeh of course, doh... I was comparing the mod "create synonym" and "merge" UIs (which are the same)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling kinda dupe: [Let's have one set of terminology for tag synonyms, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295283/307988)

Comment: Huh. I have never been confused by this, and I certainly don't have intimate knowledge about *any* databases. In the POST query, it looks like they're called `removeTag` and `masterTag`. Not sure if that is clearer? In English: "Tag to Remove" and "Master Tag".